# how to move operator double to cpp file

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to move the operator double() function below to cpp, but I don't know how to write it correctly. Thank you.

```
template <typename T> class Max {
public:
  Max() = default;
  operator T() const { return Max<T>(); }
};

template <> class Max<double> {
public:
  Max() = default;
  operator double() const // how to move this implementation to cpp?
  {
    return MAX_REAL; // defined else where
  }
};
```

I want to move the operator double function to a cpp and keep the declaration in the header file like below. But it doesn't seem right.

Min.h

```
template <typename T> class Max {
public:
  Max() = default;
  operator T() const { return Max<T>(); }
};

template <> class Max<double> {
public:
  Max() = default;
  operator double() const;
};
```

Max.cpp

```
#include "Min.h"
template <> Max<double>::operator double() {
  return MAX_REAL;
}
```

Comment: it's not clear what you want to achieve. Can you explain in words what you want to be able to *do* after you've implemented that? (Please add it to your question by **editing** it, not just adding a comment here.)

Comment: Have you tried moving it to a cpp file? What happened?

Comment: ***it doesn't seem right*** Why do you think so? Does it throw any errors?

Comment: You declare the conversion operator as `const`, but where is that `const` in the definition (implementation)?

Comment: Please indent your code, it's hard to read. :|

Comment: Unrelated to your question but do you try to reimplement [`std::numberic_limits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `const` in your definition, and `template<>` has to be removed.

So instead:

```
#include "Min.h"
template <> Max<double>::operator double() { 
  return MAX_REAL;
}
```

it has to be:

```
#include "Min.h"
Max<double>::operator double() const {
  return MAX_REAL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after some trial and error, below seems to compile alright.

```
#include "Min.h"
Max<double>::operator double() {
  return MAX_REAL;
}
```